# copy folders using nsis installer, display only one status window for copying multiple folders , copy multiple folders together

Tags: file, installation, copy, nsis

CopyFiles of NSIS installer displays different "Windows Status windows of the copy operation" when copying different folders, but i want that only one status window is shown ,whether i copy one or two or five folders, like in Windows, when we select two folders , then only a single COPY STATUS Window is shown in which the progress of copy operation for both the folders is displayed.

Is this possible? I want to copy multiple folders, but show only one status window of the copy operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `CopyFiles` which only allows a single "from" path. Here are three alternatives:

- You could do the first, check the error flag to see if the user cancelled it and if it's not set use `/SILENT` on the second.
- You could use `/SILENT` on both (personally I never use CopyFiles *without* /SILENT as I don't *want* the user to be able to cancel it).
- If you really want to, you could do it with a direct DLL call - I don't know what the function would be and I expect you would need to construct a null-separated double-null-terminated string, all of which is fiddly with NSIS. I doubt that you'll think it's worth it. If you really want to do it this way, for a null-separated string use [NullByte.nsh](http://portableapps.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/portableapps/launcher/raw-file/tip/Other/Source/NullByte.nsh) which we at PortableApps.com wrote for the PortableApps.com Launcher (for dealing with kernel32::GetPrivateProfileSection - we've since switched to parsing the INI file in pure NSIS as it's faster and not buggy; we will also use for dealing with services).